# How can I move files to a directory using Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

like so

````
► add language identifier to highlight code

```python
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
````

► put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

► *italic* or **bold**

► indent code by 4 spaces

► backtick escapes `like _so_`

► quote by placing > at start of line

► to make links (use https whenever possible)
https://example.com
[example](https://example.com)
[example](https://example.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var request = require('request');
fs.ensureDir('css');
request('http://agar.io/css/master.css').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('master.css'));
fs.move('master.css', 'css/master.css', function (err) {
  if (err)
      console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Do not forget to remove (`fs.unlink`) your `css/master.css` on rerun.

Comment: This works, just tested it. Seems to be an issue related to omitting the callback, which you should have to log errors and help yourself anyways :)

Comment: @udidu 's answer is more correct and works with no errors: request is async, so you need to wait for end before move. Anyway, you can move to any name like this: `fs.move('master.css', 'css/NEWNAME.css', function (err) { if (err) console.error(err); });`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the pipe ends to write into the stream before moving the file around.

You can try this:

```js
var fs = require('fs-extra') // This imports the fs-extra dependency
var request = require('request') // This imports the request dependency

fs.ensureDirSync('css') // This creates a folder called css

var stream = request('http://agar.io/css/master.css').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('master.css')) // This downloads the master.css file

stream.on('end', function() {
        fs.move('master.css', 'css')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `fs.move('master.css', 'css/master.css')`